# How do I change the order of the bars on this bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn's count plot function to plot Prosper Ratings.

[image: The plot.]

The code used to create the plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize = [10, 8])
sb.countplot(data = clean_loan_data, x = 'ProsperRating', color = base_color);
plt.xlabel('Prosper Rating')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Prosper Rating Counts');
```

The issue I want to resolve is the order of the bars. Currently, the order is A, D, B, E, C, AA, and HR. Why is this the set order and how do I change it? To be clear, I want to move each bar as well as its label. The order that is needed is AA, A, B, C, D, E, and HR.

Comment: What does `clean_loan_data` look like?

Comment: `clean_loan_data` is a pandas DataFrame. It has LoanOriginalAmount, BorrowerRate, BorrowerState, ListingCategory, ProsperScore, ProsperRating, EmploymentStatus, and DebtToIncomeRatio as its columns.

Comment: Is it sorted by ProsperRating? If not, try that, then feed it into Seaborn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the order via the `order=` parameter. If you also would want to assign individual colors, use `palette=`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

ratings = ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'HR']
colors = ['crimson', 'limegreen', 'dodgerblue', 'gold', 'blueviolet', 'darkturquoise', 'fuchsia']
samples = np.repeat(ratings, np.random.randint(10, 100, len(ratings)))
np.random.shuffle(samples)
clean_loan_data = pd.DataFrame({'ProsperRating': samples})

plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])
sns.countplot(data=clean_loan_data, x='ProsperRating', palette=colors, order=ratings)
plt.xlabel('Prosper Rating')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Prosper Rating Counts')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]